# const member isn't explicitly initialized but compiles

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, g++, constants

I heard that const members must be explicitly intialized, but the following compiles for me:

```
class someClass
{
    int const x;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your compiler version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a class has const-qualified member variables, then for any constructor defined for that class, those variables must be initialized in the constructor initializer list.  If any defined constructor does not initialize a const-qualified member variable, the program is ill-formed.

In your example code, `someClass` has no user-declared constructors, so there is an implicitly declared default constructor.  However, if that constructor is not used, then it is not defined.  Since you do not instantiate any `someClass` object, the constructor is not used.  Hence, your example code does not have any errors.

If you were to define a constructor for the class and not initialize the const member,

```
class someClass
{
    someClass() { } // error, does not initialize const-qualified x
    int const x;
};
```

or if you were to instantiate an instance of `someClass` (which would cause the implicitly declared default constructor to be defined), then the program would be ill-formed.

Comment: I think you meant "define a constructor"?

Comment: @Jacob:  Destructor... constructor... same thing, right?  :-O  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    someClass obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Since you haven't instantiated your object, your compiler didn't throw an error. You probably know the right way to initialize `x` but I'm putting it down just in case.

```
class someClass
{
    int const  x;
public:
    someClass():x(10){}
};
```